# How does this PHP error happen?

Tags: php, apache

In my `index.php`, I have something like this (simplified):

```
session_start();

// some code, login, etc

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ die(); }

// continues

include('function.prepare.foodlist.session.php');

// more code
```

Yet, in my apache2's error log, this error returns **sometimes** (I cannot reproduce it personally, but it sometimes happen from other users):

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: user in /path/to/function.prepare.foodlist.session.php on line 37

How can this happen?

**EDIT**

Per request, the line 37 in the `function.prepare.foodlist.session.php` file reads:

```
`foodlist-categories`.`name-".$_SESSION['user']['language']."` as `catname`
```

Comment: Please post the function file with line numbers if possible.

Comment: Maybe `function.prepare.foodlist.session.php` gets called directly/from another script, where no previous check has happened?

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is, but that line is being called. So if it is being called, you can get the error? Everything that happens before the `die` line is called will still happen (and cause errors, warnings etc)

Comment: i agree with CBroe, try putting debug_print_backtrace (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) before the line in function.prepare.foodlist.session.php and see if the file is called from your index or from other files. Is it possible that somewhere you call session_start() again and it reset your sessions?

Comment: @Nanne: "Everything that happens before the die line is called will still happen (and cause errors, warnings etc)" Really? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Not really. Code is executed sequencially. So you need to make sure all your code is correct, or at least do your checks in the absolute beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning indicates that you are using array index "user" does not define.
Before you can use $_SESSION['user'], you should check whether the index/key 'user' is in the array $_SESSION.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['language'])) {
    //do something with $_SESSION['user']['language'] like your code:
    `foodlist-categories`.`name-".$_SESSION['user']['language']."` as `catname`
} else {
    // default
   `foodlist-categories`.`name-en` as `catname`
}
```

**It's probably a user who has not yet signed, or which expired cookie, or You unset $_SESSION['user'] before this line, or you call session_start() onece again.**

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

it could actually be hard to suggest from where is the call to function.prepare.foodlist.session.php made but to avoid this notice, perhaps you may add isset() before line-37, something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  // line 37
  // etc.
}
```

It also might be that your session is perhaps getting lost before line-37 by some piece of code that is conditionally executed or it might be that the session expires on its own.

Hope it helps!